# How to optimize per pixel lighting on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing a scene in 3D using per pixel lighting on Android in OpenGL ES 2.0. When I render only a few small objects I get 60 FPS, but if I try to use a landscape to put the objects on, the framerate drops heavily, to about 15 frames. I guess this is because it has to calculate the lighting for all those pixels from the landscape. Is there any way I could optimize this? I wouldn't want to use per vertex lighting on the landscape alone because I would like to cast shadows on it.

Comment: can you put your rendering code? it will help pointing to the right direction

Comment: I cannot post code because it's too much. I tried to explain as well as I could.

Comment: just post the part that you suspect, it should be a good start?

Comment: It's not about the code. I have a surface/landscape that occupies a lot of pixels on the screen and causes the rendering to take longer with per pixel lighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments above I see that you believe the code of shaders could not be faster than it is and you are stuck into GPU fillrate limit.

In this case you can improve performance with wise culling of object: first draw nearest objects which use fast and simple shaders and which occlude your landscape object (which uses complex shaders for per-pixel lighting). This way GPU will draw only visible parts of landscape, doing less heavy computations in landscape shader. In my case I was able to gain extra 3 fps by reordering objects to more effectively occlude each other.

However, if performance drop is really that huge you can post code of your shaders, maybe there are some ways to improve performance of shaders too.

Comment: Very well-thought answer, but I' already doing it. Still, I appreciate a lot a well-thought answer. I thought about optimizing it the most and I'd say it's about 85% there. If I won't be able to optimize it enough, I think I will draw the landscape per vertex while also increasing the number of faces in the landscape to emulate per pixel lighting.

Comment: @dragostis I was just thinking about proposing to use vertex data instead of per-pixel computations. :) For example, we've used vertex data to store AO color and it looks quite good on mesh with 3000 vertices.

Comment: Exactly my thought.:) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to partition your landscape depending on distance to camera. For the nearest partition you can draw per pixel and also add more objects and detail. For far partition use vertex lighting. Also use impostors for really far objects. When you partition your landscape, you need take into your model how much area of the near landscape is projected into screen space, because if you are near the ground and let the player see down, all your screen will need to be renderer with per-pixel lighting and will suffer from rate drop.